# Computational complexity and the big $\mathcal{O}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, asymptotics

I have a question about this Big $\mathcal{O}$ problem. I have the question down $90\%$, but the other $10\%$ isn't getting to me. I will write out the entire question and I'll point out the step, which I am confused about. This is an exercise in the book too so it might seem easy but nevertheless, I am slow at math...

Q: Let $f$, $g$ be mappings from positive integers to real numbers, given by $$f(n) = 5n\,,\quad g(n) = n^2$$ for all positive integers, $n$. If we compute $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ for numbers $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$ we find that $$f(n)>g(n)$$

However, with any number greater than or equal to $5$ we find that $$g(n)≥f(n)$$

**So, with $m = 1$ and $k= 5$, we find that:**

$$ n≥k\,,\quad|f(n)|≤  m|g(n)|$$

Can someone explain to my why $m = 1$ because, according to my textbook, $m$ is supposed to bound $f$ but I don't understand how $1$ could possibly be the upper bound of $f(n)$.

Comment: Hmmm, $m$ didn't appear until you stated $m=1$.  It seems like it is just a constant, and is actually unnecessary to include here.  Aside from this problem, you could have other functions $f,g$ for which $m \neq 1$ is interesting.

Comment: $1$ doesn't bound $f$ by itself, it has help from $g(n)=n^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$m$ is not an upper bound on $f(n)$, but $m \cdot g(n)$ is. By the definition of Big-Oh notation, if we want to say $f(n) = O(g(n))$, then we need to show there exists some $m$ such that $m \cdot |g(n)|$ is an upper bound on $|f(n)|$ for all $n \geq k$.

In the given example, $m=1$ and $k=5$ lead to a perfectly valid proof, but they're not the only possible combination of values. For example, if we choose $m=6$ and $k=1$, we see that for all $n \geq k$, $|f(n)| \leq m|g(n)|$.
That is, for all $n\geq 1$, $5n \leq 6n^2$.

Comment: So whatever m x cardinality of g(n), f(n) will never go above it correct?

Comment: What do you mean by cardinality?

Comment: what I mean is, for my example in the textbook when n is 5 or greater, does m have to be 1? I know that for m = 1,2,3,4.. ect works as well, but we choose 1 because it is the smallest number that works?

Comment: Would it still be valid if I said m = 2 and k= 5..?

Comment: You don't have to choose 1! You're writing the proof. You get to choose whatever values you want so long as they work. m=2 and k=5 would work great. Your textbook author probably chose 1 because she or he thought the example would seem simpler if m was 1.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying things up!

Comment: You're very welcome